# OpenGL Compute Shader is 14x slower than 'same' OpenCL Kernel. Why?

Tags: performance, opengl, opencl, compute-shader

I have a little game that I'd like to port to Android.  The PC version originally used (and still can use) OpenCL for collision detection which shows a speed up of 230x(!) over the cpu implementation.  I'd like to move the parallel programming to OpenGL using Compute Shaders to cut out ocl, keeping it all in ogl land.  I have my first ogl compute shader using code that is functionally identical to the ocl version but, it's 14x slower than the ocl version!

I've read posts here about performance with ogl compute shaders and they're usually regarding accessing textures.  I don't have textures, just two SSBOs; one for input, one for output.

The task is an nbody problem, with the code (brute force) checking everything against everything else.  The program can have thousands of points (with any number being added and removed per iteration).  I'd like to have as many concurrent points as I can.

For 2000 points the times are:

- cpu:    713.0 ms
- ogl compute shader:  44.0 ms
- ocl:      3.1 ms

basically:

```
for (Point * p1: points) {
    for (Point * p2: points) {      
        // perform collision detection
        // calculate and accumulate any repulsive force on p1
    }
}
```

The purpose of the parallel program is to flatten the top loop.  So it's a naive implementation but that's fine for me for now. - If it's good enough for a 230x speed up with ocl than ogl shouldn't be too far behind, right?

The c++ code:

```
void Render::compute (int num_stuff, PointCSData * data, PointCSData_Out *& data_out) {

    // data IN
    glBindBuffer (GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, csbo);
    glBufferData (GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, num_stuff * sizeof(PointCSData), data, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
    glUnmapBuffer (GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);

    // data OUT - prep space
    glBindBuffer (GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, csbo_out);
    glBufferData (GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, num_stuff * sizeof(PointCSData_Out), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);  
    glUnmapBuffer (GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);

    glBindBufferBase (GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, csbo);
    glBindBufferBase (GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, csbo_out);

    glUseProgram (computeProgram);
    glDispatchCompute (num_stuff / 32, 32, 1);
    glMemoryBarrier (GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);

    glBindBuffer (GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, csbo_out);

    GLuint bufMask = GL_MAP_READ_BIT;
    data_out = (PointCSData_Out *) glMapBufferRange (GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, num_stuff * sizeof(PointCSData_Out), bufMask);

    glUnmapBuffer (GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);
    glUseProgram (0);
}
```

The shader:

```
#version 430 

struct PointData {
    int is_fixed;
    float posx, posy;
    int thingpntr;

    float friction;     // not used
    float rigidity;
    vec2 vel;           // not used
};

struct PointData_Out {
    vec2 acc;
    vec2 accrig;
};

layout (std430, binding=0) buffer cs_data {
    PointData data [ ];
};

layout (std430, binding=1) buffer cs_data_out {
    PointData_Out data_out [ ];
};

layout (local_size_x = 32, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

void main () {

    float k = 500.0;    // Hookes_K
    float d = 8.0;      // collision_d

    uint n = gl_NumWorkGroups.x * gl_NumWorkGroups.y;  // num stuff
    uint gid = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x; 

    if (data [gid].thingpntr == -1          // skip if padding point
        || data [gid].is_fixed == 1)        // skip if fixed point
            return;

    float rig = data [gid].rigidity;

    vec2 p1_pos = vec2 (data [gid].posx, data [gid].posy);
    vec2 p2_pos;

    vec2 acc;       // accumulators
    vec2 accrig; 

    float f, h;
    vec2 dif;
    vec2 norm;
    vec2 F; 

    for (uint i=0; i<n; i++) {

        if (data [gid].thingpntr == data [i].thingpntr   // skip if of same thing
            || data [i].thingpntr == -1                 // skip if padding point
            || i == gid)                                // skip if self
                continue;   

        p2_pos = vec2 (data [i].posx, data [i].posy);

        h = distance (p2_pos, p1_pos);
        if (h > d || h == 0.0)  continue;

        f = k * (h - d); 

        dif = p2_pos - p1_pos;      
        norm = dif / h;
        F = norm * f;

        acc += F * (1.0 - rig);
        accrig += F * rig;
    }

    data_out [gid].acc = acc;
    data_out [gid].accrig = accrig;
}
```

Could it something with the *access* bitfields when calling glBufferData() and glMapBufferRange()?

Again, what's making the ogl compute shader version run so much slower than a functionally identical ocl verion?

Comment: Could the android have less resources for opengl than opencl when compared to pc? 14x less for example?

Comment: It's all on the same PC for now.  I"m _planning_ to port to Android but not there yet.  I'm supposing it's how I've set up the compute shader but dunno.

Comment: @pawel - Why are you looping `num_stuff` times inside the shader? I mean if  at `P1` you found that `P1` intersected `P100`. Then why check that again when you are at `P100`

Comment: Because for p1 I find (p1,p100) and apply the force onto p1, then for p100 I find the force (p100, p1) and apply onto p100.  If I applied the force onto both (in equal but opposite directions) at p1 then when I got to p100 I'd have to somehow 'know' that p100 has already been visited by p1.  But because it's all in parallel nothing can be guarenteed to be done 'before' anything else, so I update each point independantly.  And this is slightly beside the point as the same method (good or bad) in ocl is 14x faster - which is the point, and the question.

Comment: Regarding your deleted question, you may find a discussion platform would be a better home for it. Have you tried Reddit? There are some good dev forums there, IMO, and they might welcome trying out a new image format.

Comment: (When PNG was new, the creators published a website to extol the virtues of the format compared to GIF and JPEG, and at the time getting widespread browser support looked like an insurmountable task. And now look where we are!)

Comment: @halfer Thanks.  I was wondering why comments were showing up on my old posts. :)  That's what you need to do to communicate 'freely' here now-a-days.  Anyway.  Thank you.  May try Reddit.

Comment: (Yeah, sadly one cannot comment on deleted posts, but I guess that's the idea!)